# gbm3 - GBMFit class supported by PMML?

Tags: r, boosting, pmml

Since `gbm` has been orphaned, `gbm` users are asked to use `gbm3` package.

The model produced using the `gbm` package produces a `gbm` object. While models produced using `gbm3` package produces `GBMFit` object.

Are `GBMFit` objects supported by PMML?

I tried googling and searching in stack, but couldn't find any topic on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this a question for the developers of the `gbm3` package?

Comment: @usεr11852 - true. Did I post in the wrong forum?I wanted to email them but held it off unless nobody can answer that question here. Also, posting it here would benefit all other users like me who will have same question in the future.

Comment: As a package developer myself I can tell you I would welcome such a question. If PMML is indeed supported I would make sure that this is explicitly mentioned in the documentation (if not done already) if PMML is not supported I would make a `feature-request` issue. A post here that it might be seen by the developers (or might not) and it might be up-to-date in the time of writing (or might become soon obsolete) is not preferable. Anyway, I did not vote for the question to close, maybe there is a quick "Yes/No" answer. :)

Comment: @usεr11852 - thanks for the suggestion. I'll reach out them now and hope any of them will be able to answer this post here. I'll also make the `feature-request` if not yet available :) thanks, mate!

Comment: Posted the question in [github](https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm3/issues/152). also searched in their [repository](https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm3/search?q=pmml&type=Code) for **pmml** keyword, can't find any except for the issue I raised. it might be that `GBMFit` object is really not supported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone's benefit, copying a response to my github [question](https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm3/issues/152) courtesy of `r2pmml` author **Villu Ruusmann**.

> @hansvomkreuz Convert your GBMFit object to the "old" gbm object using the gbm3::to_old_gbm(x) function, and then export using the r2pmml package as usual.
>
> Please do not use the default pmml package for PMML export, as it is known to generate incorrect model files.

If you have other answers, please share.